# Why is my Thinkpad T590 overheating even though fan control runs at 127?

Tags: temperature, fan

I have a problem with my thinkpad T590 on which I recently installed Linux Mint 20.1 Ulissa instead of Windows. I never had a problem with overheating before that but now my laptop regularly looses all functionality due to overheating.

The machine gets very hot and then one by one devices stop working. It starts with the bluetooth devices, but after a few minutes even the laptop keyboard does not respond anymore.

I also have TLP installed but turning it of and on and restarting the pc does not seem to make a difference. I was wondering if maybe TLP has the ability to overclock a CPU if I don't set the `CPU-SCALING-MAX-FREQ-ON-AC` higher than the possible processor frequency, even after I( disabled TLP.

I enabled fan_control and even successfully set the fan speed to 127 all the time but the laptop still overheats regularly.

It is remarkable that when i open powertop i catch a glimpse of 1 or 2 firefox processes that use between 10-30 Watts even though I don't have a significant amounts of tabs open and I am not using any website that is more special than youtube or linkedin.
The processes usually disappear within seconds after I open powertop.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the root of the problem?

```
$ inxi -G 
Graphics: 
    Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
    Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX250] driver: nvidia v: 460.91.03     
    Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
    OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

Comment: Does your T590 have discrete graphics? Hybrid graphics (both a discreete and an onboard graphics card)? Can you show us the output of `inxi -G` (you might need to install it with `sudo apt install inxi`). And what do you mean exactly by "overheating"? Does the machine turn off? Or is it just hotter than Windows?

Comment: inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX250] driver: nvidia v: 460.91.03 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3

Comment: the machine gets very hot and then one by one devices stop working . it starts with the bluetooth devices but after a few minutes even the laptop keyboard does not respond anymore. I was wondering if maybe TLP has the ability to overclock a CPU if I don't set the CPU-SCALING-MAX-FREQ-ON-AC higher than the possible processor frequency , even after i disabled TLP

Comment: Did you check the ventilation outlets? They can collect enough dust to make cooling difficult. I have to vacuum the side of mine every now and then, when I notice the fan stays at full speed for long times. I don't know how long ago Windows worked, but if you have it installed, you can boot it and see what happens. That will help you rule out the hardware.

Comment: Yes, I did. When I switched to Linux I also put in a new M.2 SSD harddrive (Samsung Evo Pro) and cleaned the fan while doing this. I also switched back to my old windows harddrive once for a gaming session and that worked just fine compared to a little normal usage during a work day. I am 99% sure it is a software issue.

Comment: Can you hear the fan spinning fast? Could it be that it's simply not accelerating as it should? Do you have any monitoring tools that report the fan RPM (e.g. `lm-sensors` or `conky`)? If so, can you confirm that the RPM values change as the machine gets hotter?

Comment: Yes, I can hear the fan and feel the air getting blown out depending on the settings. Since the problem persists I even set the fan to the maximum speed of 127 manually, i can hear it accelerating from the lower settings of 0 - 7 but the machine still overheats on the highest fan speed